# How to populate avro nested map structure

Tags: avro

Has anyone used `GenericData.Record` with Avro and nested map records. Giving the below schema, I am struggling to populate the `GenericData.Record` within a map:

```
 {"name": "log_data", "type":
   [ "null",
     { "type": "map", "values":
       { "type": "record",
         "name": "TypeValuePair",
         "fields": [
           {"name": "type", "type": "string"},
           {"name": "value", "type": ["null", "string"]}
         ]
       }
     }
   ]
 }
```

The java code:

```
Schema mapSchema = schema.getField("log_data").schema().getTypes().get(1);

//The code below fails

GenericRecord typeValuePair =
    new GenericData.Record(mapSchema.getField("TypeValuePair").schema());
```

with:

```
org.apache.avro.AvroRuntimeException: Not a record..
```

Any idea how I should be building setting a map within avro schema that holds values of type record?

Answer (score 6):

I was able to get this to work with following code:

```
Schema mapSchema = schema.getField("log_data").schema().getTypes().get(1);

GenericRecord typeValuePair =  
              new GenericData.Record(mapSchema.getValueType());

ImmutableMap.Builder<String, GenericRecord> logDataBuilder = 
              ImmutableMap.<String, GenericRecord>builder();

typeValuePair.put("type","string");
typeValuePair.put("value", "field1 value");
logDataBuilder.put("field1", typeValuePair);

//Set the log_data map field in the schema
GenericRecordBuilder grb = new GenericRecordBuilder(schema);
grb.set("log_data", logDataBuilder.build());
grb.build();
```

Answer (score 1):

Below should work

```
GenericRecord typeValuePair =
new GenericData.Record(mapSchema.getField("TypeValuePair").schema().getTypes().get(1));
```